# How to remove an object from a list that is not present in another list in R

Tags: r, list, filter

I have two list of objects `list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa` and `list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa` with different length. I only want to keep the objects from the `list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa` which are  in `list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa`. The common atrribute is the Tile name. I have tried the line of code below but I could not manage to get what I want.

```
list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa<- lapply(list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa, y=list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa, function (x,y) {
  remove(x[!x@data$Tile %in% y@data$Tile], list=ls())
})
```

Does somebody have an idea of a better approach?

Comment: Could you show some dput output

Comment: My list of objects are s4 object vector, so I cannot unfortunately.

Comment: If the above code works, then why do you want to change it

Comment: It is does not work because there is no removal.

Comment: Without much details, it is hard to test

Comment: Yes I know. I am jsut looking for the right function I could use. I have tried that one as well but I still have some bugs `unlist(list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa[sapply(list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa, y=list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa, function(x,y) !inherits(x, if(x[!x@data$Tile %in% y@data$Tile])))])
`

Comment: Just like Richard Herron created a small reproducible example, you could also create one.  This would possibly avoid the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update answer based on Richard Herron's answer

```
ForestInDef <- sapply(list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa, function(x) {
  as.logical(max(sapply(list_shp_Deforested_2000_Africa, function(y) identical(x@data$Tile[1], y@data$Tile[1]))))
}
)

list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa <- list_shp_Forest_2000_Africa[ForestInDef]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this scales to your problem, but I would use nested `sapply` calls. I don't know of an `%in%` operator to check vectors in lists.

```
listOne <- lapply(1:10, FUN=function(x) seq(x))
listTwo <- lapply(9:10, FUN=function(x) seq(x))
oneInTwo <- sapply(listOne, FUN=function(x) {
       as.logical(max(sapply(listTwo, FUN=function(y) identical(x, y))))
}
)
listThree <- listOne[oneInTwo]
listThree
```

Which yields the following.

```
> listThree
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[[2]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: The approach looks to work. I just need to find the right condition in the function y which result in `x@data$Tile %in% y@data$Tile`

Comment: Basically, I have a matrix oneInTwo with True and false value. So I want to keep the object from my listOne with a true value in my OneinTow matrix. However, the `listOne[oneInTwo]` step does not seem to do this job. Do you know why? 
`

Comment: @SimonBesnard `oneInTwo` is logical vector, not a matrix. In your code is it a matrix? That would explain your hack in your answer. It would be helpful if you provided a minimal working example. You may have some odd data/setup that my solution doesn't address. But my solution fits your description.

Comment: It is a vector at the end. However, all the values are False in the oneInTwo vector. Basically, `identical(x, y)` step does not detect any identical object.  I have tried `identical(x@data$Tile, y@data$Tile)` which is what I am looking for but I have some bugs still. Do you have an email where I can send you two rda files with the two lists?

Comment: @SimonBesnard please show to the `dput` of one element (vector) in each of these lists (or `head(sapply(listOne, class))`). I suspect this fails because your vectors are different classes so that even though they *appear* identical, they are not identical.

Comment: @SimonBesnard I think you need to recreate the problem in some test data that we can quickly replicate. Providing good test data makes everything much easier/faster.

Comment: I posted an answer based on ur answer which works very well. Thansk much for your help.